How to replicate blank topics in Mirror maker 2
As a part of migration from one AWS MSK (v2.2.1) to another AWS MSK (v3.5.1), we are planning to make use of mirror maker 2 to replicate topics and topic events. However i was able to setup the replication fine with topics with messages, i had few edge cases where we wanted to replicate the topics with no events (topics with 0 messages) which was necessary for some of our services to mark as healthy. How to get this done?  It is essential for us to create the topics with 0 events and this should be utmost done using mirror maker rather doing this manually as it would be tedious for   our process.
Mirror maker version : kafka_2.12-3.5.0
I tried a couple of config changes like below in the consumer properties:
source->target.enable.topic.creation = true
I tried these things :

create a new topic in source cluster with no events --> topic not getting replicated in target cluster.
publish at least one event in the source topic in source cluster --> topics and event gets pushed to target cluster.


In my actual tests, using MM2 can migrate empty topic. Can you provide more information to help find the cause?
At the same time, you can check whether an empty Topic was actually created normally, rather than being automatically created when you send a message. The criteria are quite simple, just list the Topics and see if the empty Topic exists.
Through the code, what I can confirm is that MM2 does it this way
private Set<String> listTopics(Admin adminClient) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  return adminCall(
    () -> adminClient.listTopics().names().get(),
    () -> "list topics on " + actualClusterAlias(adminClient) + " cluster"
  );
}

List<TopicPartition> findSourceTopicPartitions() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
  Set<String> topics = listTopics(sourceAdminClient).stream()
    .filter(this::shouldReplicateTopic)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  return describeTopics(sourceAdminClient, topics).stream()
    .flatMap(MirrorSourceConnector::expandTopicDescription)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

